# python flask can't find '__main__' module in ''

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Hi All I am just learning about flask. I have used pip to install it. Then when I run this basic code I get an error. Basically I see its working then abruptly exits with the following error. This maybe looks to be some environment issue but I'm not sure. The strange thing this was working the other day now it's not.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000, host='0.0.0.0') 

 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in ''
```

Comment: Could you please show your directory structure and the command you use to start the programm?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was going into the python shell and pasting the code into the shell. Some reason when I do that I hit my error. But it I run my program via python3 example.py then everything is working. I have no idea why I can't do this from the shell but that seemed to be my issue.

Comment: @bytes1234 Running anything remotely complicated by copy pasting code into the shell is bound to be unreliable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You said, that the problem only occurs when you run the code from an interactive shell. It is caused by a feature in `werkzeug` (the wsgi server `flask` is based on).

In debug mode `werkzeug` will automatically restart your server if a project file is changed. Everytime a change is detected `werkzeug` restarts the **file** that was initially started. Even the first start is done via the **file name**!

But in the interactive shell there is no file at all and `werkzeug` thinks your file is called `""` (empty string). It then tries to run that file. For some reason it also thinks that the `""` refers to a package. But since that package does not exist it also cannot have a `__main__` module, hence the error.

You can simulate that error by running `""` directly

```
python ""
# prints: can't find '__main__' module in ''
```

You could try to disabe the reloader by setting debug to `False` (which is also the default):

```
app.run(debug=False, ...)
```

Then it should also run in an interactive session. But why would you do that? Just put in a file and run that.