# Can't find __main__ when initializing my SQLite database

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Python and even newer to Flask. When I'm trying to initialize my database using SQLAlchemy I get an error. Does anyone know what's going on and how I can resolve this issue so I can run `db.create_table()` to initialize my database and to test my API endpoints?

I enter:

```
python3
from app import db
```

The error:

```
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: on
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
/Users/mark/Documents/Coding/friend_code/venv/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '/Users/mark/Documents/Coding/friend_code'
```

And this is my entire code inside app.py

```
import os
import secrets
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

users = []
theme = [
    {'neon red and neon blue': ('rgb(255, 60, 40)', 'rgb(10, 185, 230)')},
    {'gray': ('rgb(130, 130, 130)', 'rgb(130, 130, 130)')},
    {'blue and neon yellow': ('rgb(70, 85, 230)', 'rgb(230, 255, 0)')},
    {'neon pink and neon green': ('rgb(255, 50, 120)', 'rgb(30, 220, 0)')},
    {'neon purple and neon orange': ('rgb(180, 0, 245)', 'rgb(250, 160, 5)')},
    {'neon yellow': ('rgb(250, 160, 5)', 'rgb(250, 160, 5)')}
]

app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + \
    os.path.join(basedir, 'db.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

# initializion
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)


# user class/model
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    avatar = db.Column(db.String, default='default.jpg', nullable=False,)
    friend_code = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    update_code = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    theme = db.Column(db.String, default='neon red and neon blue')
    dark_mode = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, username, avatar, friend_code, update_code, theme, dark_mode):
        self.username = username
        self.avatar = avatar
        self.friend_code = friend_code
        self.update_code = update_code
        self.theme = theme
        self.dark_mode = dark_mode


# user schema
class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    # allowed visible fields
    class Meta:
        fields = ('username', 'avatar', 'friend_code',
                  'update_code', 'theme', 'dark_mode')


# initialization
user_schema = UserSchema()

# GET
@app.route('/<username>', methods=['GET'])
def get(username):
    user = User.query.get(username)
    return user_schema.jsonify(user)

# POST
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    username = request.json['username']
    avatar = request.json['avatar']
    friend_code = request.json['friend_code']
    update_code = secrets.token_urlsafe(8)
    theme = request.json['theme']
    dark_mode = request.json['dark_mode']

    new_user = User(username, avatar, friend_code,
                    update_code, theme, dark_mode)

    # add to db
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

    return user_schema.jsonify(new_user)


# run server
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Is it similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087283/python-flask-cant-find-main-module-in? It says to try `Debug=False`.

Comment: That didn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you invoking your code? If you are calling directly, like with

```sh
$ python app.py
```

then you need to wrap the `app.run()` command inside of a **main** block at the end of `app.py`

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Otherwise if you are trying to invoke the *package* directly, like with

```sh
$ python -m friend_code
```

then you need to include a `__main__.py` file inside the folder which contains the block of code with the **main** block (as well as with the import statement for `app`).

The issue is that your *run server* function call is being executed every time you try to import the database from that file, because it is not wrapped with one of these **main** blocks.

You can read more about how this works from [this in-depth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

With regard to creating your database tables the simplest method would be creating a file which handles this for you, which you can then run directly

`create_db.py`

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from app import db
    db.create_all()
    print("Database Created")
```